# ng-repeat filter on json object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a complex JSON structure as below:

My JSON object  is like -

```
$scope.data = {
    "Test 1": [
      {
          "paperName": "Physics Test",
          "lkExamTypePk": 1,
          "paperPK": "20",
          "lkExamType": 2
      }
    ],
    "Test 2": [
      {
          "paperName": "Maths Test",
          "lkExamTypePk": 2,
          "paperPK": "23",
          "lkExamType": 3
      }
    ]
}
```

I am using this json to display in my html page and want to search key which is Test 1, Test 2, etc:

```
<input ng-model="filter.key" />
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key,val) in controllerName.data | filter:filter.key">
        <td>
            {{key}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But the problem is that filter works on array and on the values of JSON and I am getting error of not an array.

Error which I'm getting at the console

> Error: [filter:notarray]

[image]

Comment: i've tested it on codepen, it seems to work. post yout error please

Comment: @firegloves Thanks for taking out time.

Comment: This is the error which I am getting in console:----- angular.js:14525 Error: [filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/filter/notarray?p0=%7B%22Test%201%22%3A%5B%7B%22paperName%22%3A%22Physics%20Test%22%2C%22lkExamTypePk%22%3A1%2C%22paperPK%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22lkExamType%22%3A2%7D%5D%2C%22Test%202%22%3A%5B%7B%22paperName%22%3A%22Maths%20Test%22%2C%22lkExamTypePk%22%3A2%2C%22paperPK%22%3A%2223%22%2C%22lkExamType%22%3A3%7D%5D%7D
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:20743

Answer (score 2):

I think you problem is in how you refer your variabile. As I can see you are declaring your `data` array into `$scope` variabile with

```
$scope.data = { ... }
```

Then you try to access it referring to your controller with

```
controllerName.data
```

You can follow 2 different approaches, but you can't mix them.

**1) $scope variabile**

If you want to work into `$scope`, in your controller you must declare your variabile as follow:

```
$scope.data = { ... }
```

then into html you must refer to it like this (without controllerName):

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key,val) in data | filter:filter.key">
```

**2) controller scope**

If you want to work into controller's scope, in your controller you must declare your variabile as follow:

```
this.data = { ... }
```

then into html you can refer to it like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key,val) in controllerName.data | filter:filter.key">
```

**Hint**

Generally a good practice, when you receive an error referring to a variable, is to print your variable's data into html to check that you are referring well to it, something like:

```
<pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>
```

**Try with array instead of object**

You can try using an array intead of a json object, as suggested by the error, something like this:

```
$scope.data = [
    "Test 1": [{
      "paperName": "Physics Test",
      "lkExamTypePk": 1,
      "paperPK": "20",
      "lkExamType": 2
    }],
    "Test 2": [{
      "paperName": "Maths Test",
      "lkExamTypePk": 2,
      "paperPK": "23",
      "lkExamType": 3
    }]
  ]
```

Comment: Stil same result